# Reach root of function scope

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Is there a way to reference the root of the scope of a function.

If an object "myObject" has vars "s0, s1 & s2", it is possible to reach them via a for loop like this:

```
for(var i:int = 0; i < 3; i++)
    trace(myObject['s'+i]);
```

Or even using 'this' if code is into object:

```
for(var i:int = 0; i < 3; i++)
    trace(this['s'+i]);
```

Is there a way to do so inside a function :

```
var s0:String = 'xx';
var s1:String = 'yy';
var s2:String = 'zz';

function func(s0:String, s1:String, s2:String)
{
    for(var i:int = 0; i < 3; i++)
        trace(this['s'+i]);
}

func('aa','bb','cc');
```

Where func would trace 'aa', 'bb' & 'cc' instead of 'xx', 'yy' & 'zz' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `arguments` object which is available in a function to provide you information about the parameters which were passed to it (see [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f56.html)):

```
var s0:String = 'xx';
var s1:String = 'yy';
var s2:String = 'zz';

function func(s0:String, s1:String, s2:String)
{
    for(var i:int = 0; i < arguments.length; i++)
        trace(arguments[i]);
}

func('aa','bb','cc');
```